# Reporting Services paragraf

Tags: c#, reporting, service

How to add paragraf to Microsoft Reporting textbox?

When i put empty chars, they are not rendered, i try with Functions Space, LSet... VbTab....

For example

i want

```
This is text
```

But i get

This is text

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone give some sugestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, put the following in the Value property of your Report TextBox:

```
="     Text here"
```

This will handle the whitespaces.

Comment: No, it will not, i alredy try this, but it dosent work.
Any other solution?

Comment: Strange, as this works for me.  Make sure you also put the equal symbol